# How to Approve Jenkins Scripted Pipeline RejectedAccessException for groovy.io.FileType FILES?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, sandbox, jenkins-groovy

I have a scripted Jenkins Pipeline and cannot approve the sandbox restriction for `groovy.io.FileType FILES`. For example the following Jenkins Pipeline snippet does not work in the sandbox out of the box:

```
new File("/tmp").eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->
    echo "$file"
}
```

An exception is thrown:

```
Exception stacktrace: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticField groovy.io.FileType FILES
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectStaticField(StaticWhitelist.java:199)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor$14.reject(SandboxInterceptor.java:372)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:381)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
at WorkflowScript.copySqlFiles(WorkflowScript:101)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:58)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:136)
...
```

Normally an entry is created for this type in 
`Manage Jenkins » In-process Script Approval`, but for this exception not. This is really strange, because if I traverse directories with `new File("/tmp").eachFileRecurse(FileType.DIRECTORIES)` it is working and I could approve the exception, but now there is no approval entry generated for `FILES`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to use the Groovy Script Console via Sub-URL `.../script` and running the following script:

```
def signature = 'staticField groovy.io.FileType FILES'
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval.get().approveSignature(signature)
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to work with Jenkins Pipelines is to follow the provided scripts. In this case just use the [findFiles Utility step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace)

It doesn't seems to be possible to find directories but you can find files recursively in sub folders using the [ant-like pattern matching](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).

To iterate over all the files in a sub folder of your workspace you could write this:

```
findFiles(glob: 'special/path/**/*').each {
    echo "${WORKSPACE}/${it.path}"
}
```

Comment: Very interesting link, but very limited API in my eyes, what I really do is both:
new File("${env.WORKSPACE/special/path}").eachFileRecurse(FileType.DIRECTORIES) { dir ->
                dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->
echo "${file.getAbsolutePath()}"
                }
}
How could I do this with findFiles? Is there even a way to limit execution to directories at all?

Comment: If you just want to find the files you can do this with my updated answer, however finding the directories only seems not to be possible with the findFiles step